# What happens to an individual atom in an antimatter reaction?

Tags: science-based, physics, antimatter, nuclear-chemistry

So the answers to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/215841/antimatter-accident-afterglow) I asked about an antimatter accident got me thinking about the particulars of interactions better atoms and subatomic antimatter. I'm assuming an antiproton would annihilate a proton from the nucleus and then something, but is that necessarily true or can the anti-particle interact with a sufficient mass of normal particles of any kind. Is the energy of that annihilation enough to destroy the atom or does it become a new isotope as if it had undergone normal radioactive decay. And so on.

So lets take a particular example; what exactly happens to an individual atom of lets say neodymium when it comes into contact with an antiproton during a magnetic bottle failure?

Thinking about this slightly more there may be several possible scenarios; I'm primarily interested in the most likely outcome/series of reactions but a list of contingencies would be a welcome addition.

Comment: Have you considered asking this on Physics?

Comment: @L.Dutch Yes, I tend to get better information here, the physics stack is great for data that takes hours/days to decipher, answers from Worldbuilding tend to be more immediately usable. Also this is a follow up and I have edited it as such.

Comment: just specify you are a laymen when you ask the question on the physics stack.

Comment: Questions that can be answered on other stacks are not automatically off-topic on the WB.SE. It still might be a good idea to include some worldbuilding context.

Comment: I would vote to reopen this if [worldbuilding was the problem](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8488/40609). In other words, why do you need to know this? How will it affect the rules of your world? Note that I would expect an as-asked answer to be something boring and along the lines of, "not much, you'll end up with an ion of Praseodymium, which won't exist for very long...." One anti-proton won't start a chain reaction, which requires a critical-mass event.

Answer (score 5):

The annihilation of an anti-proton is messy.

A proton is made up of two up quarks and one down quark, and some gluons.

$uud$  proton

$\bar{u}\bar{u}\bar{d}$  anti-proton

The bar of the top indicates anti-particles.

The annhilation reaction is going to start with up-anti-up or down-anti-down. This will produce a pair of photons and take away two of the quarks out of the six. Say it's the ups that go first. Now you have this.

$ud \text{ } \bar{u}\bar{d}$ plus photons

The photons here will be in the range of 300 MeV. (As pointed out by one of the comments, possibly up to the 800 MeV range if a pion forms.) That is *way* hard. The photons in a typical x-ray machine, for example, are usually less than 0.1 MeV.

The photons go away, *probably* not doing much to the remaining atom. But now you have these particles left behind. They could also annhilate and go away as photons. Or they could form pions that would rapidly decay into photons and electrons. These processes produce a variety of different energy radiation, some of it in the same 300 MeV range. (Again, maybe 800 MeV.)

That would just pluck one proton out of the atom, moving it one space to the left on the periodic table. At that point it will depend what isotope it starts as. For example, if it was iron, the most common isotope is Fe-56. That would lose one proton and so become Manganese, and also lose one in its atomic weight, so it would be Mn-55. Which is stable. Iron has four stable isotopes.

Fe-54  => Mn-53  3.74 million year half life, electron capture to Cr-53

Fe-56  => Mn-55  stable

Fe-57  => Mn-56  beta to Fe-56  stable

Fe-58  => Mn-57  beta to Fe-57  stable

Other chemical elements will have different patterns.

But the messiness is not finished.  The $ud \text{ } \bar{u}\bar{d}$ particles, or indeed the photons, could cause the nucleus of the affected atom to break apart. There is plenty of energy here to pull fragments of various size off the nucleus. If that happens you will get a complicated array of fragments, many of which are radioactive and will decay to other things, some quickly some slowly. Some will be chemical elements in the fewer-proton part of the periodic table.

Now, could the anti-proton interact with a neutron?  Yes.

A neturon is one up quark and two down quarks.

$udd$  neutron

For example, the anti-proton's $\bar{u}$ anti-up quark could annihilate the neutrons $u$ up quark. This will again leave a collection of quarks behind that could either annhilate or form mesons, which will quickly decay. This is similar to the proton-anti-proton case. The main difference is that now what is removed from the atom is one neutron.

Looking at iron as the example again, the four isotopes would do the following.

Fe-54  => Fe-53 which beta decays to Mn-53, seen previously

Fe-56  => Fe-55 which beta decays to Mn-55, stable

Fe-57  => Fe-56 stable

Fe-58  => Fe-57 stable

So to summarize. You are going to get some very hard photons for sure, and possibly some higher energy electrons. You are quite likely to get some residual radioactivity, probably of much lower energy, photons for sure, probably betas and alphas. And you will get some lower atomic weight isotopes, most probably only one or two steps away from the starting atom.

Another comment talks about conservation of momentum. Yes, this could be important. If there is significant recoil the nucleus could get a huge kick. This could mean the nucleus acts as radiation directly. Or it could mean the nucleus, minus one proton or neutron, gets fragmented further, and the fragments fly away as radiation. I have zero experience with such interactions, so I can't estimate how frequent they might be.

So to summarize. You are going to get some very hard photons for sure, and possibly some higher energy electrons. You are quite likely to get some residual radioactivity, probably of much lower energy, photons for sure, probably betas and alphas. And you will get some lower atomic weight isotopes, most probably only one or two steps away from the starting atom.

Comment: Sounds like a nuclear physicist's wet dream...

Comment: @Aganju Actually, nuclear physics does not usually deal with anti-protons. Nuclear is usually limited to about 10 MeV. To get an anti-proton you need to get into the GeV range at minimum. So nukies never see them. We do see positrons in some interactions.

Comment: Imho i's not that easy. First of all this reaction [is less likely than simple scattering](https://news.fnal.gov/2014/02/seeing-double-in-proton-antiproton-collisions). I would presume this is due to gluon interactions needed for quark-antiquark pairs of wrong color. (a u can only annihilate with a ubar if they have opposite color charge). The extra interactions will scale down the S-Matrix and thus the overall cross-section.  Then are you sure about the 300 MeV? If we consider the process to be working and actual pions forming, the mass difference is about 800 MeV.

Comment: Lets not forget conservation of momentum.

Comment: @infinitezero  The 300 MeV assumes pairs of photons. If a pion is 800 MeV then photons in the 400 MeV range. I'm going by roughly-one-third of a nucleon mass. Scattering is most likely, but if an anti-proton gets tossed at an object it becomes likely to get slowed down by electrical interactions, then find something to hit. I'm a nukie, give me a break! :^)

Comment: @Aron There may well be recoil. But there might not be much, since if it makes a pion (or some other particle) that could carry most of the kinetic energy with it.  It is exceptionally messy.

Comment: A pion is ~135 MeV, a nucleon is about 940, so the difference is about 800. As Aron says, two photons will form (since there's no rest frame for a real photon, conservation of momentum demands two photons).

Comment: Lets not forget Nuclear Isomers :D

Answer (score 3):

From my layman understanding of nuclear physics, I think the process would go as follows:

1. the antiproton gets annihilated by a single nucleon, be it a proton or a neutron
2. the annihilation releases energy in form of a gamma photon, whose energy is around thousands of MeV
3. when this photon interacts with a nucleus, it will deliver thousands times more energy than the nuclear binding energy (see chart below)

[image]

4. incapable of managing that much energy, the nucleus "pops", breaking apart into highly energetic nucleons flying around
5. when those nucleons interact with other nuclei, depending on their energy, will either pop them again (delivered energy greater than the nuclear binding energy, go back to step 4) or make them radioactive (delivered energy smaller than the nuclear binding energy).

Comment: Why would an antiproton interact with a *neutron*?

Comment: @MontyWild A neutron is still a proton, just with a bonded electron, at least according to my first year nuclear chemistry module.

Comment: @MontyWild https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321375906434

Comment: @L.Dutch That's paywalled... but I looked it up on Wikipedia.  You learn something every day...

Comment: However, wouldn't the antiproton be repelled by the electrons (same charge) unless it was going fast enough?

Comment: @Ash Your chemistry module was wrong. A neutron isn't a proton plus an electron, and antiproton + neutron → electron (+ photons) isn't possible. Antiproton + neutron → virtual W → electron + antineutrino (+ photons) is possible, but I imagine the rate would be very low. The article that L.Dutch linked is about antiproton + neutron → pions. Calling any of these "annihilation" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @MontyWild ish, but as [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) means that making antimatter confinement devices is Really Awkward, preventing that antiproton from interacting with a nucleon purely by elctrostatic repulsion is basically impractical (but [maybe not impossible](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0969-806X(03)00195-6), paywalled, sorry).

Comment: @MontyWild an anti proton will absolutely interact with a neutron, just not for the reasons Ash states. Protons and Neutrons are both types of Baryons, which are bound states of Quarks. These could form a pair of mesons and a lot of energy.

Comment: @MontyWild To first order, that same repulsion would be cancelled out by the attraction of the nucleus (assuming an atom rather than an ion). To the 4th order however, the electrons, being mobile would be pushed to the far side of the atom (slightly), resulting in the electron cloud being biased away from the nucleus, thus resulting in something similar to Van der Waals.

Answer (score 2):

The fission of a heavy nucleus requires a total input energy of about 7 to 8 million electron volts (MeV) to initially overcome the nuclear force which holds the nucleus into a spherical or nearly spherical shape as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission).

When proton anti-proton annihilate, 2 GeV of energy is released which may start a fission reaction in fissionable material. In other materials, maybe gamma rays will emerge and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

So, to reiterate some of the stuff I said in [my answer to your last question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/215860/62341), and because no-one else has really mentioned it in their answers: the most interesting things are going to involve the unstable baryons that come out of the annihilation reaction, typically pions.

The things doing the actual annihilation are the constituent quarks of the antinucleon, and the nucleon it collides with. The odds of the both nucleons going up in a puff of gamma rays is pretty slim, and so mostly what happens is that of the 6 quarks present at the beginning of the reaction, 2 will annihilate and the remaining four will pair up to form a [meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson) of some kind (often [pions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion), which are the things people care about in many kinds of antimatter rocket or power source design). The most common outcome of the nucleon-antinucleon reaction is the formation of two mesons, which will carry away the bulk of the momentum and mass-energy of the original particles... this will typically be twice as the prompt gamma rays, and therefore is the major influence on what happens next.

The most important thing about the mesons is that, being [baryons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon), is that they can interact via the [strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) and therefore have a significant chance of interacting with the "spectator" nucleons that make up the rest of the nucleus of the atom that the original antinucleon hit. This might mean scattering off them, for example, which is a good way to impart some of the meson's considerable momentum to the nucleus which can then cause it to fission.

The various cross-sections (eg. probabilities) for gamma-ray-nucleon interaction and meson-nucleon interaction, and then the various probabilities for fission or shedding energy by emitting gamma rays are too many and too complex for me to research or list here. So I won't.

I'll just some up the rest as bullet points.

- Nucleus is either transmuted to a lighter isotope (due to a neutron being annihilated) or to a lighter elements (due to a proton being annihilated).
- Nucleus *may* gain extra energy via interaction with prompt gamma rays from the annihilation, or via interaction with mesons formed from un-annihilated valence quarks from the annihilated nucleon-antinucleon pair.
- If it does, it *may* undergo fission, or shed this energy by ejecting an alpha particle, or by proton or neutron emission.
- The new nucleus *may* be unstable, in which case it may undergo radioactive decay, eg. by alpha or beta emission (or less commonly proton or neutron emission).
- The final nucleus *may* be in an excited state, in which case it will release some or all of that additional energy in the form of gamma rays.

**Tl;DR: its a radioactive mess.**